# django - database - from sqlite to postgres, not fully migrated, lacking language support?

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

I just deployed my very first django project, and I am trying to use `pgloader` v3.5 to migrate some important data from `sqlite3` to `postgres`. It's successful, well, semi-successful since the data written in English are migrated whereas the data written in Russian (Cyrillic) aren't.

### Tried:

Then, I tried a generic way - dump a `datadump.json` file of `db.sqlite3` and `python manage.py loaddata datadump.json`, then the error:

> django.db.utils.DataError: Problem installing fixture '/home/user/project/datadump.json': Could not load boutique.Category(pk=1): character with byte sequence 0xd0 0x90 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1"

### `datadump.json`

Then, I checked the `datadump.json` file:

```
[{"model": "boutique.category", "pk": 1, "fields": {"gender": 1, "name": "\u0410\u043a\u0441\u0435\u0441\u0441\u0443\u0430\u0440\u044b", "description": "", "uploaded_date": "2020-03-02T08:20:49.786Z"}}, ...
```

### checked

I checked the data in `db.sqlite3` is intact, and data (mainly strings) in Russian aren't transferred in the new `postgres` database.

### system

Ubuntu 18, bionic
django 3.0.3

---

### Question:

I think the question is how to load/convert non-English json data? Not sure where to start to solve the problem. Thanks in advance!

---

## Additional Info:

Thank you so much guys! Now I know the encoding is wrong:

```sql
postgres=# \l
                              List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |    Access privileges     
-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+--------------------------
 postgres  | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US   | en_US | 
 template0 | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US   | en_US | =c/postgres             +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US   | en_US | =c/postgres             +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 va        | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US   | en_US | =Tc/postgres            +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres   +
           |          |          |         |       | va_db_admin=CTc/postgres
```

Does this mean I have to recreate the database?

Comment: Looks like your database or tables are not created with the right encoding.

Comment: I remember this was the code executed when setting up the postgres db: `ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';` so `utf8` isn't correct? Should I set it to what instead? Cheers!

Comment: Database encoding can only set at database creation time with `createdb` executable or `CREATE DATABASE` sql statement. Current encoding can be checked with  `\l` psql meta command.

Comment: UTF8 should be correct for database encoding but `client_encoding` is a parameter used by the database client for automatic conversion between client and database, it is not the database encoding setting used at database creation time.

Comment: Oh dear... Does this mean I have to recreate the database? Please see the additional info above. Thank you so much btw!!

Comment: Yes you have to recreate your database with UTF8 encoding.